# clearTimeout not working in recursion function - javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

Here is the code I am using. When ticks becomes equal to 5 the recursion function should stop clearing the mainThread timeout. Anybody please help.

```
var mainThread;  
var ticks = 0;  
function tickTimer() {  
    clearTimeout(mainThread);  
    if (ticks >= 5) {  
        endGame();  
    }  
    else {  
        mainThread = setTimeout(function () {  
            ticks++;  
            tickTimer();  
        }, 1000);  
    }  
}
```

Let me know if any concerns.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are decreasing the value of `ticks` yet expect the game to end if the value becomes larger or equal than 5.

Comment: as @UweB mentioned, shouldn't the ```if``` condition be ```if ( ticks == 5 ) { endGame(); }``` because ```(ticks >= 5)``` will always return true?

Comment: Consider using [`setInterval`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/729921/7586) instead of calling `setTimeout` repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can try this. all you need to do is clear interval every time tickTimer function is called.

var  mainThread = setInterval(tickTimer, 1000);
var ticks = 0;

function tickTimer() {       
    if (++ticks >= 5)  {
        clearInterval (mainThread); 
        endGame();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Great! Sheel. It worked. BTW loxxy has given the same type of answer. and is working.

Comment: @sheelpriy Adding your insight to someone's answer is wonderful. But always make an effort to give credits, if any.

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
function tickTimer() {       
    if (++ticks >= 5)  {
        clearInterval (mainThread); 
        endGame();  
    }  
} 

var  mainThread = setInterval(tickTimer, 1000);
var ticks = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare `mainThread` ? Like this

```
var mainThread = null;
function tickTimer() {  
    clearTimeout(mainThread);
    mainThread = null;  
    if (ticks >= 5) {  
        endGame();  
    }  
    else {  
        mainThread = setTimeout(function () {  
            ticks++;  
            tickTimer();  
        }, 1000);  
    }  
}
```

And `ticks++` not `ticks--`

Answer (score 1):

Please try to replace `ticks--` to `ticks++`

Answer (score 0):

I've think just send your timer as argument

```
function tickTimer(timer) {  
    timer && clearTimeout(timer);  
    if (ticks >= 5) {  
        endGame();  
    }  
    else {  
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {  
            ticks--;  
            tickTimer(timer);  
        }, 1000);  
    }  
}
```

Don't use global scope )))

Answer (score 0):

I thing you should Initialize variable ticks as the function is triggered.